# find out the location of satellite using Augmented Reality

Tags: ios

I have develop application for iPhone.In my app,I would like to track all dish installations via barcode and picture along with gps co-orinates of installation. They would also like to have an augmented reality module(similar in terms of functionality to 1. The app will allow taking pictures of the dish installation.

```
The app will capture GPS co-ordinates of the installation area.

The app will allow the installer to point the phone to the sky and find out the location of satellite using Augmented Reality

The app will work without internet connection.
```